# Custom text editor in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uilabel, uitextview

everybody, I would like to know if in iOS there is a way to write some text, using a custom cursor, letting the user edit (I mean, press backspace) just the last n characters typed in and disabling copy-paste and magnifying glass.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: disable copy/paste in interface builder

Comment: And what about the cursor, the magnifyng glass and the editable text? I thought a label would be the best choice since every time I add a character I can call a method that refreshes the label's text adding the character to it.

Comment: need more info i do not understand what you want to do